# Remove dots from strings in R

Tags: r, string, numeric

I want to remove all dots in a *df* column of prices, all integers. The data:

```
df <- data.frame(price = c(1.800.000, 900.000, 1.500.000, ...))
```

I want:

```
price
1800000
900000
1500000
```

I have tried `gsub('.', '', as.character(df$price))`, but I got only empty strings.

What could I do?

Comment: `gsub('.','', x, fixed =TRUE)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
gsub('\\.', '', as.character(df$price))
```